# How to get a duration in FFmpeg that corresponds to the number of frames that can be read?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, metadata

I'm a developer of the Python MoviePy package and I'm trying to rework how we import file information to be more robust.

I need to get the duration of any videofile such that when multiplied with the media's fps value (in this case, `tbr`), it equals the number of frames in the video.

I've found 3 solutions:

```
(1) ffmpeg -i broken_video.mp4
(2) ffmpeg -i broken_video.mp4 -f null -
(3) ffmpeg -i broken_video.mp4 -codec copy -f null -
```

FFmpeg reports that the video has 29.90 fps, 30 tbr, and contains 305 frames.

They all list `Duration: 00:00:10.26` near the top. I believe that this is derived from the metadata and has proved to be unreliable, so I'd rather avoid using this. In this case, 10.26x30=307.8

(2) has `time=00:00:10.21` near the bottom. 10.21x30=306.3. Also, this one is a lot slower since it is re-encoding the entire file.

(3) has `time=00:00:10.19` 10.19x30=305.7. This is the closest to 305, although it still rounds incorrectly.

I've also considered simply taking the tbr and the number of frames and generating the duration from this (in this case, 30x305= 10.16667), but occasionally the tbr is something crazy like 10k and would surely create an incorrect duration.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: If it's a broken video then any answer is just guesswork anyway.

Comment: If you're getting that from the file name, that is not what I intended. Unless you are saying that the durations not matching mean that it is 'broken'?

Comment: Well yes to both. Have you tried a known good test video to see if the times match? If the tbr is 10k then it is definitely a broken video.

Comment: Usually, the 3 values are very similar if not identical. However consider `fire2.mp4`: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/media/fire2.mp4. It has '10.51 fps, 90k tbr' and the three duration values are 2.38, 2.41, 2.39. 25 frames total. It is a legitimate video taken on a kindle fire with no transformations applied to it since.

Comment: And even if the files are broken/wrong, I'd like the system to deal with them as best as is possible. This is for a generic Python library that will be used on all kinds of video/audio.

Comment: As an (ex) software developer myself, I would looking at the fmpeg source or asking the ffmpeg developers for their opinions on this. How you handle it in your software is 1/ not relevant for anybody not using your software and 2/ off topic here (we don't deal with programming). I don't think [so] would take the question either and I'm not sure there is another SE site that would. It may fly on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com but I would ask in their chatroom first before posting there.

Comment: There's no robust method across all formats. For MP4, use ffprobe to look at the timestamp of the last frame. And the value you want is fps, not tbr. tbr is the inverse of the smallest interval between frames. fps is average interval. For formats without a global sample index, those values are derived by ffmpeg's probing which won't involve looking at all frames.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look at the FFmpeg mailing list.